# MS SQL 2014 TSQL pulling 3 records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to pick the 3 rows that have the 3 unique GUID's below:

```
  SELECT 
    number                                  AS 'ID #', 
    line                                    AS 'Line #', 
    network                                 AS Network,
    FORMAT(SUM(totalCost), N'c', 'en-US')   AS Total 
  FROM 
    theLine 
  WHERE 
    theGuid = '32e1319d-8842-4b98-9a66-c1e694417528' 
  AND 
    theGuid = '61e819a8-a37a-4105-aab0-e34df31d992d' 
  AND
    theGuid = '6675811d-9a32-4b62-a003-87344af03d6b' 
  GROUP BY 
    number, line, network
```

However, when I run this query I get no records back. If I just do **1 WHERE clause** then I get that record related to that GUID but any more renders no results.

But what I need it to do is the following:

```
------------------------------------
|ID #  |Line # |Network |Total     |
------------------------------------
|1     |1      |USASV   |$5,000.00 |
|2     |1      |FJESC   |$4,920.00 |
|3     |1      |RTDEW   |$598.00   |
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use OR not And for this

Comment: That is because there is no row where theGuid is simultaneously all three values. You would need to use IN for this type of thing.

Comment: Ugg I figured it was going to be something small @SeanLange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have 3 different values all in the same row. Either change your `AND` to `OR` or use the `IN` operator.

```
  SELECT 
    number                                  AS 'ID #', 
    line                                    AS 'Line #', 
    network                                 AS Network,
    FORMAT(SUM(totalCost), N'c', 'en-US')   AS Total 
  FROM 
    theLine 
  WHERE 
    theGuid = '32e1319d-8842-4b98-9a66-c1e694417528' 
  OR
    theGuid = '61e819a8-a37a-4105-aab0-e34df31d992d' 
  OR
    theGuid = '6675811d-9a32-4b62-a003-87344af03d6b' 
  GROUP BY 
    number, line, network
```

Or:

```
  SELECT 
    number                                  AS 'ID #', 
    line                                    AS 'Line #', 
    network                                 AS Network,
    FORMAT(SUM(totalCost), N'c', 'en-US')   AS Total 
  FROM 
    theLine 
  WHERE 
    theGuid IN (
                '32e1319d-8842-4b98-9a66-c1e694417528',
                '61e819a8-a37a-4105-aab0-e34df31d992d',
                '6675811d-9a32-4b62-a003-87344af03d6b' 
               )
  GROUP BY 
    number, line, network
```

Comment: Nice one, Zohar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use OR instead of AND in your WHERE clause

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer Ryan

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example use case for `IN` though i'm not sure why you have a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
    number                                  AS 'ID #', 
    line                                    AS 'Line #', 
    network                                 AS Network,
    FORMAT(SUM(totalCost), N'c', 'en-US')   AS Total 
 FROM 
    theLine 
 where theGuid in ('32e1319d-8842-4b98-9a66-c1e694417528','61e819a8-a37a-4105-aab0-e34df31d992d','6675811d-9a32-4b62-a003-87344af03d6b' )
GROUP BY 
number, line, network
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer scsimon

Comment: No sweat brother.